Yarn workspaces usage with local @types package
I am struggling with few issues related to package managements in my project using yarn workspaces.
So, I have a React Native mobile app (1st package) using a "lowcode engine" (2nd package) that generates screens based on JSON config and using a set of UI components from a design system package combining React Native Web and storybook stuff (3rd package).
The lowcode / JSON config is prepared in a React.js web admin app (4th package) by including 3rd and 4th packages for preview.
Finally I need to share some types/interfaces/classes between 2nd and 3rd package, so I created a package in "@types/engine" (5th package).
All the packages are exclusively TS and uses vite (except the mobile app => metro)
Here's my root package.json file :
{
    "name": "monorepo",
    "private": true,
    "packageManager": "yarn@4.5.1",
    "workspaces": [
        "./@types/*",
        "Mobile",
        "Engine",
        "Admin",
        "DesignSystems/*"
    ],
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/node": "^22.9.0",
        "eslint": "^8.57.1",
        "prettier": "^3.3.3",
        "ts-node": "^10.9.2"
    },
    "type": "module"
}

Main issue : my import { ... } from '@types/engine'; statements are not working, VSCode tells me that it cannot import type declaration and recommend to use 'engine' instead of '@types/engine' ... ts(6137) module "/Users/.../monorepo/@types/engine/index"
Weird because it clearly indicates 'monorepo/@types/engine/index'
The @types/engine folder contains this package.json :
{
    "name": "@types/engine",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "types": "index.d.ts",
    "main": "dist/index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "tsc index.d.ts --outDir dist/"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "typescript": "^5.6.2"
    }
}

I have created inside an index.d.ts file with all the exports, and this type package is included in other packages like that : "@types/engine": "workspace:^1.0.0",
I am wondering if "@types" would not be a specific name/prefix that cannot be used for private/local packages...
Also how do I know if yarn is looking for sources OR for the transformed version of the local packages ?
My last concern about yarn install :
What is the correct way to install ? should I only use yarn install inside the monorepo root folder ? Or should I use yarn workspace MyPackages install for each package ? Or should I do both ?
Because I use nodeLinker: node-modules, and I see node_modules/ folders in the root folder AND in each package folder except in the "Admin/" folder, given it uses specific packages (like MUI) I would expect to not see them in the node_modules of the root folder ?
